# Simplest way to switch context back and forth (dispatching)

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, grand-central-dispatch, swift5

I have two classes that perform independent computation. For the sake of simplicity here, I will represent them with functions`calc1` and `calc2`. At some random places in each function, I need to sleep for a while. Rather than doing `calc1` and then `calc2`, I'd like to switch back and forth between them.

I could use threads, but it seems to me at first sight overly engineered to do so. In addition, these 2 functions need to be on the main thread, because they deal with user interface. I do not need different threads. I just need to switch from one context to another, and back where we were.

In python, there is the concept of `greenlet` (`gevent`) which allow simple context switching, without being real thread. That would be perfect for my need. Is there such a mechanism in `swift` ?

```
func calc1() {
...
sleep(300) // go to calc2
...
}

func calc2() {
...
sleep(200) // resume calc1
...
}
```

Comment: You must use threads. If you sleep a thread, by definition, no code is going to execute on that thread while it sleeps. The only way for some other code to execute is to run it on another thread. QED

Comment: I was hoping that there would be some way to replace the sleep by something that calls a grand central dispatcher, and simply proceeds to execute the code in a another contexte

Comment: Yes, there is, but I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. A `dispatch_sync` would suspend (sleep) the first thread while the second executes a block in another thread ... but to what purpose, and in what way is that different than simply calling the other function? You really need to describe what you're trying to accomplish; without that context these are just generic answers to vague questions.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is far too vague for us to give you any meaningful answer. There are just too many alternatives depending upon the details of what you are doing. I'd suggest you give us an idea of the sorts of calculations that you're doing. But it's just very confusing why you wouldn't want them to run concurrently given that GCD makes it so easy and practically all devices have multiple cores nowadays. It could end up being far more complicated to do context switching than you would to just make it run in parallel.

Comment: Ok, I tried to clarify a bit further what these functions do, and why I can't use threads. Maybe the answer is that there is no way to easily do what I want, and that's ok...

Comment: If I had two completely independent calculations that needed to periodically update the UI, for example, I'd dispatch them to background queues, do the complicated calculations off to the main thread, and then dispatch the periodic UI updates back to the main thread. That's the standard pattern. But the idea of ever sleeping, or tying up the main thread as you do complicated calculations is a non-starter. Or are you just talking about animations and the like? So many options and so little information to go on...

Comment: The exact case is so complicated that I will definitely get my question closed if try to explain it. Your solution is valid though. It does answer my specific case. I understand that 1) there is no greenlet mechanism in swift and 2) I should use threads. Feel free to post it and I’ll accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notion of alternatively switching between two computationally expensive calculations on the main thread is not going to work.

- First, we never do anything computationally expensive on the main thread. We should never block the main thread for any reason. It results in a horrible UX (your app may appear to frozen) and you risk having the app killed by the OS watchdog process (which is looking for apps that appear to be frozen and are blocking the main thread).
- Second, if calculating two truly independent calculations, we wouldn't add the overhead and complexity of trying to switch between them. We would just use GCD to dispatch them independently to background queue(s).

So, the solution for this sort of process would be to dispatch these two tasks to run concurrently on background queue(s), either to one concurrent queue or two dedicated queues. But the key is to perform the complicated calculations off of the main thread, in parallel, and then dispatch the periodic UI updates back to the main thread. But always keep the main thread free to respond to user input, system events, etc.

FWIW, this process of dispatching these two independent tasks separately is simpler and a far more efficient use of the device resources. Just synchronize updates to model objects. And dispatch groups are a great way to keep track of when two independent concurrent tasks finish.